Noises when unused inputs not shorted with common V-
Update. Manufacturer confirmed all the 4 red V+ inputs used same blue V- and ground. Now what would be the noises introduced if only channel 1 is used and the 3 other inputs are floating (all differential)?

In the above. The 4 red sockets are 4 V+ differential inputs sharing only one V- (the blue socket) and ground (the small yellow socket at bottom). The big yellow on top right is just extension adaptor with same pins if one wants to relay all of them to another device.
What will happen if only channel 1 (the one with white plug) is used and the 3 other red sockets are floating. Will they introduce any noises to the blue V- socket which is then relayed to the channel 1 (with white plug)? Or are the only noises introduced to channel 1 is only because the 3 other sockets are floating? And how will these 3 floating input affect channel 1? You can replace the image above with any instrumentation amplifier, etc. with the same connections.
Update: This is the only schematic (rough) I can get. Note for the 16 channels. There are 4 banks just like the image above with separate reference and ground between the 4 banks. I was just concerned of one bank and my question is really general in that what happens to unused inputs in amplifiers especially if they share the same V-. I could have just sketched it.


This is impossible to answer without knowing what specific instrument that is. Ideally you'd also add schematics of this device.

see update above...

"The 4 red sockets are 4 V+ differential inputs sharing only one V- (the blue socket)" the description in the second picture implies that differential inputs do not share V-, hence there are only 8 of them. Unless "bi-polar" means something completely different from "differential"

Bipolar means you can connect channel 1 to channel 2, channel 3 to 4 and so on to channel 15 to 16. Hence there are 8 of them. this is compared to Referential where all channels share one reference. I think per bank all 4 inputs share the same V-. If this is so.  Noises can be coupled to channel 1 even when channel 2 to 3 is shorted to ground only?
